# Python CSV Writerow append with a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm making a web scraper to scrape box scores for MLB games from a certain site. I'm basically trying to create a header row in my output CSV file, that consists of "Teams" and then a div class from the website that has each inning number from the game, followed by R, H, E. Normally, one could just .writerow['Teams', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'R', 'H', 'E'] to make that row, however sometimes the games go to extra innings, so that div class with the inning numbers/RHE changes dynamically, so I want the scraper to recognize that and adjust the row accordingly.

My code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('BoxScoreURLS.csv', newline='') as f_urls, open('IndividualBoxScoresOutput.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    #csv_output.writerow(['Teams', 'Box Scores'])


    for line in csv_urls:
        page = requests.get(line[0]).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        topline = soup.findAll('div', {'class' :'LineScoreCard__lineScoreColumnElement--1byQk LineScoreCard__header--3ZO_N'})

        for t in range(len(topline)):
            csv_output.writerow(['Teams', topline[t].text])
```

This is the URL I'm trying to scrape: (My code will read from a list of URL's in a separate CSV)

https://www.thescore.com/mlb/events/63853

This is what it outputs to the CSV:

```
Teams   1
Teams   2
Teams   3
Teams   4
Teams   5
Teams   6
Teams   7
Teams   8
Teams   9
Teams   R
Teams   H
Teams   E
```

And when there's a game that goes extra innings, it looks like:

```
Teams   1
Teams   2
Teams   3
Teams   4
Teams   5
Teams   6
Teams   7
Teams   8
Teams   9
Teams   10
Teams   11
Teams   R
Teams   H
Teams   E
```

And this is what I would like to see:

```
Teams   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   R   H   E
```

So 'Finding All' of that div class will gather the info correctly, but what this creates right now is two columns in the CSV. I tried several different row.append combinations too but to no success. Once I can get a solution for appending the div class to the same row as where "Teams" displays, I will have my header row to then put the scores underneath.

Is it possible to somehow loop to find all of the div class and then append it to appear horizontally across the same row as "Teams"? Let me know if I can answer any more questions.

Thank!

Comment: What about `writerow([topline[t].txt for t in range(len(topline))])`?

Comment: can you perhaps provide the sample data, of how it appears normally and how elsewise during extra innings. I can't understand with the provided information.

Comment: With the code you have given, the problem cannot be recreated by us. Can you [edit] the question to include the necessary information to allow us to run it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for the suggestion, however when I tried it, it didn't actually output anything, but I thought that would have worked!?

Comment: @hsnsd Certainly I will put up another answer with more information.

CORRECTION: I will update my initial question to provide the info.

Comment: @MartinEvans thanks! I have updated the question with more information. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @MattWilson: My bad :-( I wrote `txt` when it is `text` (notice the **`e`**). What you want is `writerow(['Teams'] + [topline[t].text for t in range(len(topline))])`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Excellent! Sorry I missed the e too. Works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

@SergeBallesta provided me with a perfect solution.

writerow(['Teams'] + [topline[t].text for t in range(len(topline))])

Thanks a lot!